Using zod form validation with radio button group that has no default checked value on first render
I have a simple form that I am using zod to validate. For simplicity let's say the form has exactly one user field for specifying a selection:
const FormSchema = z.object({
    options: z.enum(["option-0", "option-1", "option-2"], {
        required_error: "You must select an option",
    })
})

export default function Form() {
    const form = useForm < z.infer < typeof FormSchema >> ({
        resolver: zodResolver(FormSchema),
        defaultValues: {
            options: "",
        },
    })

    const onSubmit = useCallback(async (data: z.infer<typeof FormSchema>) => {
        console.log(data)
    }, [])

    return (
            <form onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)} 
            ...
            </form>
    )
}

The above code does not work since "" is not in the set of options specified in the FormSchema.
Is there a way to:

Have no radio buttons selected on first render
Still use zod validation onSubmit to ensure the value for the radio button group is within the set specified?

